# How to format computer just after BIOS and before OS is loaded

Tags: windows, bios, formatting, format

I have a bunch of computers to format (desktops and laptops). Until now, I used an usb key with the windows' boot but it's not really fast.

Do you know a script (on a usb key) that can run before the OS is loaded at start up and format the computer ? I don't need to install a fresh os, just format drives.

The purpose is that theses computers, wiped of everything, will be given to companies that will recycle them for others stuffs.

Note : I have to totally wipe the drive, not quick format.

Thank you

Comment: Make sure that you write the *entire* drive to wipe - *no* quick format. That taking a while, booting Windows, Linux, or even DOS doesn't really make that much of a difference.

Comment: There are many bootable wiping tools that run from USB. What research have you done and what have you tried?

Comment: I searched something like "Usb key format drive before os boot" and phrases like that. I found a lot of tool that will run a script (like the windows tool or the linux boot) but I wanted (and almost hoped) to find something that will automatically format the main harddrive (ou ask for it) after the BIOS boot.

Answer (score 3):

Most often I have seen used is [DBAN](https://dban.org/) (Darik's Boot and Nuke) which is a small 16MB iso image that can be written to a CD or USB stick and will boot and wipe hard disks.

Comment: +1 There are many [alternatives to DBAN](https://alternativeto.net/software/dban/) you could have a look at.

Comment: @harrymc Do any of these alternatives actually work on flash devices?

Comment: I don't know - you will have to check them out.

Answer (score 0):

I always liked to use Hiren's boot, the program is loaded on a USB and it has some programs like:
a disk partitioner - formatter
Recuva to recover lost files
HDD disk diagnostic tools like CrystalDisk to check disk's health

You just load onto the USB flash and then start working on whatever you need.
Used it a lot to do IT Tech stuff on PCs that had malfunctioned.

Hope it helps!
Regards,